# Select a certain map element in a list using PartiQL (DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

Although I understood how to select a list item in a map using document paths (eg Devices.FireStick.DateWatched[0]),I cannot figure out how to do it the other way round.
Say, I have an attribute containing a list of maps:

```
"Text": [
  {
   "Right": "Line one, right text",
   "Left": "Line one, left text"
  },
  {
   "Right": "Line two, right text",
   "Left": "Line two, left text"
  }]
```

and I want to get the left text of line one in my PartiQL select. My naive approach:

```
select Text[0].Right  from mytable where ID='123'
```

did not result in success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-quote [DynamoDB reserved words](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html), such as "right".

Here's a working PartiQL query:

```
SELECT Text[0]."Right" FROM mytable WHERE id = '1'
```

Also, note that if your table name includes a hyphen then quote that too, for example:

```
SELECT Text[0]."Right" FROM "mytable-xyz" WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: what if I want an ORDER BY, how can I include that index in the query as well?

Comment: @dontdownvoteme the [reference document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html) indicates support for ORDER BY. If you have an issue using it, it would be better to open a new question.